# Ignoring samples in Gibbs sampling

Tags: python, sampling, mcmc

```
import random,math

def gibbs(N=50000,thin=1000):
    x=0
    y=0
    print "Iter  x  y"
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(thin):
            x=random.gammavariate(3,1.0/(y*y+4))
            y=random.gauss(1.0/(x+1),1.0/math.sqrt(2*x+2))
        print i,x,y

gibbs()
```

The above python code is the Gibbs Sampling and the following line confuses me.

```
for j in range(thin):
```

What is the significance of that additional inner loop?

Comment: To repeat the body of the `for` loop `thin` times? (note that `x` and `y` are both read and assigned in the body)

Comment: I know. But what is the motivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason seems to be the introduction of thinning into your Gibbs sampling. Thinning is used to reduce the effect of correlation between consecutive samples. Gibbs sampling generates a Markov Chain of samples and the nearby samples are correlated, while typically the intention is to draw samples that are independent.

To achieve that, you can use only every `M-th` value, while ignoring all intermediate values. In this case `M` is stored in the variable `thinning` and you are taking only every `thinning` value which is then printed below the for loop.